# ASP.NET MVC2 Custom RoleProvider GetRolesForUser not called

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I have a situation with my ASP.NET MVC 2 application that when I use `[Authorize(Roles = "Admin,User,Test")]` attribute on any of the controller methods, my custom role provider is not called. Tricky part is that when I run the application in visual studio web dev server, this GetRolesForUser is called every time. When I install the application to IIS, this is not happening anymore.

I'm running windows 7 x64 Enterprise.

Role provider is configured in web.config as follows:

```
<roleManager defaultProvider="GTTRoleProvider" enabled="true">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="GTTRoleProvider" type="GTT.Security.GTTRoleProvider, GTT.Security" applicationName="GTT" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
```

In Role provider implementation I have this method implemented as follows:

```
public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)
        {
            if (log.IsDebugEnabled)
                log.DebugFormat("Gettings roles for user {0}", username);

            BaseConfiguration cfg = new BaseConfiguration();
            using (ISession session = cfg.OpenSession())
            {
                IUserDAO userDao = new UserDAO(session);
                GUser user = userDao.GetByUserName(username);
                return new string[] { user.BaseRole.Name };
            }
        }
```

What am I doing wrong or what am I missing?

t. Erki.

[EDIT: 1]
I managed to track down my source of problems - I had a custom Principal class implemented as well, but I supplied empty roles to base GenericPrincipal constructor. After filling this with the user's roles, everything started to work. But GetRolesForUser method is still not executed for my custom role provider.
Can anyone explain why this worked in ASP.NET development server (inside Visual Studio) and not in IIS?

Comment: Since you are using MVC2, you either have VS2008 or vs2010.  Why don't you set the project to use IIS when you run debug, and try to debug it that way

Comment: Yes, I do use VS2010, but I actually never thought I would need to debug on IIS directly. MS has said the ASP.NET development server would be enough to build the solutions (I tended to agree to small size projects, but not sure anymore...)

Comment: Having the exact same problem, my custom role provider works fine in ASP Development Server, but not in real IIS, nor IIS Express.